# Splitting and Comparing one String (Java)

Tags: java, string

I have been testing different method for a while and this is what I got. I just can't figure out how to solve this.

```
/** Return true iff s has an odd number of characters and
 *  the substring before the middle character equals the substring
 *  after it.
 * Examples: For s = "" return false
 * For s = "b" return true
 * For s = "xbx" return true
 * For s = "xxxx" return false
 * For s = "hellohello" return false
 * For s = "hello!hello" return true */
public static boolean isDoubled(String s) {
    // TODO 1. There is no need for a loop. Do not use a loop.
    // In all methods, use s1.equals(s2) and NOT s1 == s2 to test
    // equality of s1 and s2.
    int midLen = s.length() / 2;
    if (midLen == 0) return false;
    String[] parts = {s.substring(0, midLen - 1), s.substring(midLen + 1)};
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    if ((s.length() % 2 == 0) && (part1.equals(part2))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake with using `substring` function:

```
public static boolean isDoubled(String s) {
    if (s.length() % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    if (s.length() == 1)
        return true;

    int mid = s.length() / 2;
    return s.substring(0, mid).equals(s.substring(mid + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two simple mistakes:

- In your `if-statement` you have if the length is even, when you want to make sure it *isn't* even. (Change `(s.length() %2===0)` to `!(s.length() %2 == 0)`
- And the `substring` function is not inclusive, so you want to change `s.substring(0, mid-1)` to `s.substring(0, mid)`

  (From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)): "*The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.*")

Also you don't need to put the two parts of the `array` into variables. You can simply compare them like: 
    `parts[0].equals(parts[1])`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass two indices (a, b) to the substring method, the method includes index and excludes index b. Mathematically, it is [a, b). If you consider the string "hello!hello", mid will be index 5. When you say -

```
String[] parts = {s.substring(0, midLen - 1), s.substring(midLen + 1)};
```

The two parts you are getting are

```
s.substring(0, 4) //this gets you the string "hell"
s.substring(6)    //this gets you the string "hello"
```

Obviously, they do not match. resulting in false equivalence.

What you need is a small change -

```
String[] parts = {s.substring(0, midLen), s.substring(midLen + 1)};
```